# Transmitir JSON entre dispositivos com WiFi Direct

Tags: android, json

Estou precisando transmitir dados entre dispositivos via JSON e armazenar os dados no *SQLite*. Ou seja, haverá um dispositivo responsável por receber os dados e ao término irá enviar uma mensagem "OK" para o dispositivo que enviou os dados.

Estou utilizando *WiFi direct* e já implementei o habilitar da conexão, a pesquisa dos dispositivos próximos e a conexão entre eles. Gostaria de uma ideia de como enviar o JSON e receber a resposta tbem via *JSON*.

Comment: Isso ajuda de alguma forma? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715283/transfer-data-between-android-devices-using-wifi-direct

Comment: Opa... obrigado pela dica... vou ver se abre a mente... Valeu!